# Ignore headphones on Android 2.2.2

Tags: java, android

Is there a way in Android 2.2.2 to override the headphone port?

For example, a service that was able to tell the phone that headphones have been removed. The `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't look like it'd be able to tell the phone anything, just listen for when things change.

I want to do this because my LG phone thinks there's headphones in even when there is not, making it necessary to use speakerphone for all my calls.

Comment: seems like it's a hardware issue , did you tried to restore your phone ?

Comment: Yes, I've done a reset and even took it to the LG store (it's an LGP509). It's out of warranty, and I'm just desperate for a software approach instead of buying a new phone.

Comment: Ok I see , even with a software approach you will have to compile your own ROM : take a look here , this guy has almost the same problem as you : http://androidforums.com/lg-ally/369910-ol-problem-earphone-jack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am answering this question with links to a [discussion on which they point many things to solve that on a Droid X](http://forums.androidcentral.com/motorola-droid-x/104919-x-thinks-headphones-always-plugged.html). It is not an answer related with programming, since I honestly think that it is not a software issue. You can find more discussion of people with the same problem on [here](http://forums.webosnation.com/webos-tips-information-resources/281437-stuck-headset-mode-permanent-easy-fix.html), [here](http://androidforums.com/motorola-triumph/518292-warning-headset-plug-going-bad.html), and [here](http://androidforums.com/eris-support-troubleshooting/104669-eris-stuck-headset-mode-without-headset-plugged.html).

Among the suggested solutions:

- Re-plug the headphones in, and pull them out
- Maybe a piece of dust inside, try running a q-tip in it
- A person "cured" it with a factory reset

Comment: I've tried all these attempts, and am almost certain it's just bad hardware - I'm just desperate for an alternative solution (the only other is buying a new phone :P) Thanks though!